# Pilhas C++, Ordenação crescente de pilha com o menor elemento no topo

Tags: c++, classes

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Implemente um estrutura de dados do tipo pilha com as operações de empilhar e desempilhar. Adicione um método que, utilizando uma pilha auxiliar, faça a ordenação crescente da pilha original, com o menor elemento no topo da pilha. Nenhuma outra estrutura pode ser utilizada além da pilha auxiliar.

Entradas:

Quantidade de elementos a serem armazenados na pilha
Elementos da pilha
Saídas:

Elementos da pilha ordenados
Exemplo de Entrada:

10
3 8 5 10 2 0 4 11 21 7
Exemplo de Saída:

0 2 3 4 5 7 8 10 11 21

Já fiz até uma certa parte, mas agora queria saber o que tenho que colocar no int main. Só criei a pilha p1, agora o usuário tem q digitar o tamanho q ele quer e os números pra depois ser ordenado. Alguém me ajuda por favor. O código:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int max_itens;
    class pilha{
        private:
            int tamanho;
            int* estrutura;
    
        public:
            pilha();
            ~pilha();
            void empilhar(int numero);
            int desempilhar();
            bool vazia();
            bool cheia();
            void ordenar(); 
    };
    pilha::pilha(){
        tamanho = 0;
        estrutura = new int[tamanho];
    }
    pilha::~pilha(){
        delete [] estrutura;
    }
    bool pilha::cheia(){
    return (tamanho == max_itens);
    }
    bool pilha::vazia(){
        return(tamanho == 0);
    }
    void pilha::empilhar( int numero){
        if(cheia()){
            cout << "Nao e possivel inserir este elemento!"<<endl;
        } else{
            estrutura[tamanho] = numero;
            tamanho++;
        }
    }

    int pilha::desempilhar(){
        if(vazia()){
            cout << "Nao tem elemento para ser removido!"<<endl;
        } else{
            tamanho--;
            return estrutura[tamanho];
        }
    }
    void pilha::ordenar(){
          int x, y, cont=0, tam=tamanho;
                pilha aux;
                bool p=true, c=true;
        
                while(tamanho!=0){
            
                    if(p){
                        x=desempilhar();
                        aux.empilhar(x);
                        cont++;
                        p=false;

                    }
                    else{
                
                        if(tamanho!=0){
                    
                                x=desempilhar();
                                y=aux.desempilhar();
                        
                        
                                if(x>y){

                        
                                    while((x>y)and(c)){
                                
                                        aux.empilhar(y);
                                        aux.empilhar(x);
                                        cont++;
                                
                                        if(tamanho!=0){
                                    
                                            y=aux.desempilhar();
                                            x=desempilhar();
                                    
                                            if(x<y){
                                        
                                                empilhar(x);
                                                aux.empilhar(y);
                                        
                                            }
                                    
                                        }
                                        else{
                                    
                                            c=false;
                                        }
                                
                                
                                    }
                            
                                }
                                else{
                            
                            
                                    while((x<y)and(cont!=0)){
                
                                
                                        empilhar(y);
                                        cont--;

                                        if(cont!=0){
                                    
                                                y=aux.desempilhar();
                                        }
                                
                                        if(x>y){
                                    
                                            aux.empilhar(y);
                                        }
                                
                                    }
                            
                                    aux.empilhar(x);
                                    cont++;
                                    p=true;

                    
                                }
                    
                    
                        }
                
                
                    }
            
    
            }


            while(tam>0){
    
            y=aux.desempilhar();
            empilhar(y);
            tam--;
    
            }

    }

    int main(){
        pilha p1;



    







        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Conhece o brinquedo das [Torres de Hanoi](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torre_de_Han%C3%B3i)? É mais ou menos o que precisa fazer. No seu programa nem criou a pilha auxiliar, que é claro que vai ter que criar. Basta empilhar o maior elemento da pilha original na auxiliar até a original estar vazia

Answer (score 0):

A lógica de toda a ordenação está no método **Pilha.Ordenar()**, então o que você deve fazer primeiro é receber os números da entrada e preencher a pilha **p1**. Após isso basta  usar o método de ordenação e depois imprimir os números ordenados.